# Why isn't forwarding reference const?

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding-reference

The forwarding reference is supposed to forward the argument to another function, right? So why isn't it const?

```
template <typename T>
void func(const T&&);
```

Non-const reference allows the function to modify its arguments (instead of just forwarding them).

Comment: Interesting question, it is possible that there is no use for this kind of signature. Either you do `T&&` or `T const&`. https://youtu.be/ZbVCGCy3mGQ?t=1194

Comment: @alfC There are uses, but they are somewhat obscure, see my answer.

Comment: Maybe, only maybe, it is a way to take anything and then *only* internally in the function promise not to modify it. Sort of `... void func(T&& t){ ... use t only as std::as_const(t) ... ; }` or as the video says, have the overload to force a certain resolution.

Comment: The `&&` means "You can modify the object, to suck out its guts", but the `const` means "You cannot modify the object".  Impasse.

Comment: @Eljay I'm not questioning that, but just to clarify, deleting isn't modifying, right?

Comment: Deleting makes the deleted function available for "best match" checking.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "deleting" is an operation on a pointer. It doesn't matter whether the pointer is itself const, or whether it is a pointer to const, it can be deleted in either case (assuming it is a pointer value that can be deleted at all; i.e. it is a valid pointer value returned by `new`).

Comment: Thanks - Glad that got in the comments. I found that a bit odd earlier so I thought it be best to get on record.

Answer (score 11):

> Why isn't forwarding reference const?

Because it is desireable to be able to *move* a perfectly forwarded xvalue. An object cannot usually be moved from a const reference, because the argument of the move constructor needs to be non-const.

Furthermore, it is desirable to be able to bind lvalues into forwarding references. It is not possible to bind lvalues into `const T&&` which is a const rvalue reference - it is not a forwarding reference at all <sup>1</sup>.

If you don't wish to move from the argument, but only constantly refer to it, then you don't need a forwarding reference. In that case a const lvalue reference is sufficient.

Example:

```
struct S {
     S() = default;
     S(S&&) = default;      // move
     S(const S&) = default; // copy
};

void foo(S fooarg);

template <typename T>
void bar(T&& bararg) { // forwarding reference
    foo(std::forward<T>(bararg));
}

// call site
S s;
bar(s);            // 1 copy
bar(S{});          // 2 move
bar(std::move(s)); // 3 move
```

Here we wish `bararg` to be moved into `fooarg` in cases 2 and 3 , and we wish it to be copied in case 1. Forwarding reference achieves this. A const rvalue reference does not, because it is not possible to pass the const reference to the move constructor.

---

Const rvalue references are only rarely useful. Standard library uses them in a [few places](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/bk8j8v/uses_of_const_t/emeu810/?context=3):

```
template <class T> void as_const(const T&&) = delete;
template <class T> void ref(const T&&) = delete;
template <class T> void cref(const T&&) = delete;
```

The intention of these deleted overloads is to prevent calling the function with a temporary argument (rvalue). `const` prevents the argument from becoming a forwarding reference, which would bind to anything and therefore make any call deleted.

```
constexpr const T&& optional::operator*() const&&;
constexpr const T&& optional::value() const &&;

template <class T, class... Types>
constexpr const T&& get(const std::variant<Types...>&& v);

template< class T, class... Types >
constexpr const T&& get(const tuple<Types...>&& t) noexcept;
```

Above, const rvalue reference is used as a return type of a wrapper when accessing the wrapped value so the value category and constness of the wrapped value is maintained.

---

<sup>1</sup> Standard (draft) says:

> [temp.deduct.call] ... A forwarding reference is an rvalue reference to a **cv-unqualified** template parameter that does not represent a template parameter of a class template (during class template argument deduction ([over.match.class.deduct])).
>   If P is a forwarding reference and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction.

Comment: Could you add a section explaining how moving from an object might change the object? (e.g, setting the data pointer to null with std::vector or std::string?)

Comment: Terminology note: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues)

Comment: I have a vague sense of what you are trying to say (I get lost with `xvalue` nomenclature), but is it fair to say that `ref(const T&&)` is there to forbid construction from temporary objects?

Comment: @alfC Yes, `ref(const T&&) = delete` is there to forbid construction from temporary (i.e. rvalue). And if it was `ref(T&&) = delete`, then it would prevent all usage, since the forwarding reference binds to anything.

Comment: Do you know an example in which the `T const&&` case is not left unimplemented or deleted?

Comment: @alfC see the optional, variant and tuple examples in the answer.